# Convert database timestamp to date

Tags: php, database, date, timestamp

I have a database timestamp with this format `2016-06-01 11:46:00` and I would like to convert and echo it to this format `Wed. 01-06-2016`.I tried a lot but no desirable results..Any ideas?

Thanks a lot, it worked!
If I want the difference between today and the past date in days or weeks I think I use `date_diff`.How exactly?

Comment: use `date()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `date` and `strtotime`:

```
$time = '2016-06-01 11:46:00';
echo date("D. d-m-Y", strtotime($time)); //Wed. 01-06-2016
```

Updates:

```
$grk = array("Tet"); // complete the rest of the array
$eng = array("Wed"); // complete the rest of the array

$time = '2016-06-01 11:46:00';
$date = date("D. d-m-Y", strtotime($time));
echo str_replace($eng, $grk, $date);
```

Comment: he needs like Wed. 01-06-2016. I think you need to update your solution.

Comment: Updated with the day.

Comment: To change `D.` in some day in other languages?

Comment: What? I can't catch you.

Comment: For example  `Wed.` to be replaced with `Tet.`

Comment: `Tet.` From where?

Comment: Perhaps I will need to create a table  with all the days in Greek language.But how can I replace the default days with the days of my array?

Comment: @platanas20 did you get the desired output? or are still looking for?

Comment: It worked great!Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = '2016-06-01 11:46:00';
echo date("D. d-m-Y", strtotime($time)); //Wed. 01-06-2016
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Any ideas how i can echo for example _6 days ago_?I use date_diff but how exactly?

Comment: For a different answer you need to make another question, What you ask here is clear.

Comment: I updated my question!It is ok I will..Thanks a lot!